# Rails: display devise sign_up form in sign_in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I found this [article](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app) for show the sign in form anywhere in your app, however how to do the same but for the sign up form instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in terminal, type `rails g devise:views`

the view path of sign in
`app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

the view path of sign up
`app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

just copy the form in sign up view to the `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`, and adjust the html and stylesheets.